# How to extract the CPU and Memory usage of the Google Cloud Kubernetes Pod when the pod is finished running

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I notice that when the job for a certain pod is finished running, and when I access this Kubernestes Engine > Workloads page. I don't see data on CPU, Memory usage anymore. Could you please let me know if there is a way to have this information for the succeeded jobs? The tester team needs to monitor the CPU and Memory for the pobs. Thank you very much in advance.

[image: CPUMEM_POD]

Comment: Hello, please tell more about the setup you're having. Is the `Job` that has this issue spawned by a `CronJob` by any chance?  I'd reckon this could be related to the "Job details UI doesn't show Pod stats" issue on `GKE`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183716551

Comment: Thank you @Dawid Kruk no in fact these jobs are being spawned by one of the api app to run simulation. We don't use CronJob.

Comment: I'd reckon the best course of actions for this would be to create an `Issue` with reproduction steps on [Google Kubernetes Engine Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Monitoring > Metrics Explorer, here: https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer .

A job is going to create a pod so you can explore metrics like `container/cpu/limit_utilization` for example.

Here you can find a detailled list of the metrics exposed by GKE:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes

Comment: thank you for your reply but my solution is using prometheus monitoring/grafana dashboard as they keeps historical data for the pod and not on google cloud console.